# Where does CarrierWave stores uploads

Tags: ruby, sinatra, carrierwave, datamapper

Please help me understand how does CarrierWave works.
I'm using minimal Sinatra/DataMapper app with following contents:

```rb
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
end

class Video
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :desc, Text
  mount_uploader :file, VideoUploader
end

get '/' do
  slim :form
end

post '/' do
  video = Video.new
  video.name = params[:name]
  video.desc = params[:desc]
  video.file = params[:file]
  video.save
  redirect '/'
end
```

As I understood `mount_uploader :file, VideoUploader` string in *Video* definition adds *.video* method to *Video* instance, and I can store uploads assigning *params[:file]* to it. When I'm trying to send form from browser, the request successfully creates record in DB table, but I can't find any signs of file existence either in DB and *public_directory*. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `video.file.path` where video is an instance of `Video`

Comment: @avlazarov am I should define this in *post* action?

Comment: After your post action succeeds(where you upload the file), get the video object in the rails console(`video = Video.last`) and then `video.file.path`

Comment: @avlazarov returns nil

Comment: Do you have the `file` column in your database? If yes, try setting the `store_dir` of the VideoUploader into a custom existing directory(e.g `def store_dir; 'public'; end`

Comment: @avlazarov *file* column doesn't exist. I've defined it myself in *File* model (is it wrong?) as *String*, but after record creation column was clear. Then I've defined *store_dir* in uploader - same result. Also *store_dir* definition doesn't help either without *file* column.

Comment: If there is not file column in your database, CarrierWave will not be able to store the filename thus it will not be able to retrieve the file. So yes, your `videos` table should have the file column.

Comment: @avlazarov am I should define it myself in model?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should define the `store_dir` method inside the `VideoUploader` class:

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
....
end
```